# If product of matrices $A$ and $B$ is defined, then $\operatorname{rank}(AB)=\operatorname{rank}(BA)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

If product of matrices $A$ and $B$ is defined, then $\operatorname{rank}(AB)=\operatorname{rank}(BA)$. Is this always true, or just in some special cases?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is trivially true if both are invertible, but not otherwise. Classic counterexample is $$A=\begin {bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end {bmatrix}, \ \ \ B=\begin {bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end {bmatrix}. $$

Answer (score 5):

The answer is no. Here is a counter-example:

$$A=\begin {bmatrix}1&1\end {bmatrix}, \ \ \ B=\begin {bmatrix}1\\-1\end {bmatrix}. $$

Answer (score 2):

It is not always true. Consider:

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} \qquad B=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
-1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

Then:

$$AB=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} \qquad BA=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$